# Add item to ComboBox in WPF mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm dealing with a ComboBox in WPF and MVVM but I can't find how to populate the ComboBox in real time.

```
private ObservableCollection<AudioListaDevice> _audiodevicesitem = new ObservableCollection<AudioListaDevice>{
//Adding my first Item to test it
        new AudioListaDevice { AudioDeviceItem = "Test 01"},
        new AudioListaDevice { AudioDeviceItem = "Test 02"},
};
        public IEnumerable<AudioListaDevice> AudioDevicesItem { get { return _audiodevicesitem; } }
        private AudioListaDevice _AudioDevice;
        public AudioListaDevice AudioDevice
        {
            get
            { return _AudioDevice; }
            set
            {
                _AudioDevice = value; OnPropertyChanged("AudioDevice");
                //On Selection 
                Debug.WriteLine(_AudioDevice.AudioDeviceItem.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is the class

```
public class AudioListaDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _AudioDeviceItem;
        public string AudioDeviceItem
        {
            get { return _AudioDeviceItem; }
            set { _AudioDeviceItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("AudioDeviceItem"); }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

What I'm trying to do is add a new item in the collection later on from anywhere and refresh the ComboBox.

```
public MainWindowVM() 
        {
            _audiodevicesitem.Add(new AudioListaDevice("Test03"));

//not relevant code continues here...
}
```

This is the Xaml Binding

```
<ComboBox x:Name="listaoutputdevices" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AudioDevicesItem}"
          DisplayMemberPath="AudioDeviceItem"
          SelectedItem="{Binding AudioDevice}" 
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="60,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="352" >
```

The error says I don't have a contructor with an argument to pass the String via AudioListaDevice, but If I declare it in the Class AudioListaDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged

```
    private string item;
    public AudioListaDevice(string item)
        {
            this.item = item;
        }
```

Then

```
private ObservableCollection<AudioListaDevice> _audiodevicesitem = new ObservableCollection<AudioListaDevice>{
//Adding my first Item to test it
        new AudioListaDevice { AudioDeviceItem = "Test 01"},
        new AudioListaDevice { AudioDeviceItem = "Test 02"},
};
```

Gives an error when adding the previous items and the ComboBox doesn't reflect the

```
_audiodevicesitem.Add(new AudioListaDevice("Test03"));
```

Thanks!:)

Comment: What is the last error message??

Comment: The point is, the parameterless constructor is optional, _only if_ there is no other constructor defined at all. It will be auto-generated in this special case. But as soon as you define a constructor, the compiler assumes that every constructor which wasn't defined was left out deliberately. This means once you have defined the constructor which takes the `string` parameter, you also have to explicitly define the parameterless constructor (if you want to) - which apparently you haven't. That's why the initialization list fails, as it invokes an undefined parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sadly, It's a little cryptic to me. I would really like some code that put me on the good direction, even if I have to rewrite it all. The point is to populate the combox the simplest way and retrieve the selected item. Thanks!

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The point is, the parameterless constructor is optional, *only if* there is no other constructor defined at all. It will be auto-generated in this special case, so that the compiler is able to create instances of the type. But as soon as you define a constructor, the compiler assumes that every constructor which wasn't defined was left out deliberately. This means once you have defined the constructor, which takes the `string` parameter, you also have to explicitly define the parameterless default constructor (if you want to) - which apparently you haven't. That's why the initialization list fails, as it invokes an undefined parameterless constructor.

```
// Invokes the parameterless default constructor
new AudioListaDevice { AudioDeviceItem = "Test 01"}
```

The solution is to define a default constructor:

```
public class AudioListaDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
  // Parameterless default constructor
  public AudioListaDevice() : this(string.Empty)
  {
  }

  public AudioListaDevice(string audioDeviceItem)
  {
    this.AudioDeviceItem = audioDeviceItem;
  }

  private string _AudioDeviceItem;
  public string AudioDeviceItem
  {
    get { return _AudioDeviceItem; }
    set { _AudioDeviceItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("AudioDeviceItem"); }
  }

  public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to define a parameterless constructor, then use the existing constructor for instantiation properly:

```
private ObservableCollection<AudioListaDevice> _audiodevicesitem = new ObservableCollection<AudioListaDevice>
{
  //Adding my first Item to test it
  new AudioListaDevice("Test 01"),
  new AudioListaDevice("Test 02")
};
```

Recommended read:

- [Microsoft Docs: Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)
- [Microsoft Docs: Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)